# Prevent certain request headers from getting logged in nginx

Tags: security, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

We are using nginx as a reverse proxy. We have a question around nginx error_log directive. If error log level is set as debug 
(error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug), nginx logs request url and all the request headers.

We are implementing api key based authentication and we are thinking of sending api key in the request headers. Is there anyway, we can prevent api key header from getting logged in nginx?

We checked for access_log directive nginx provides custom log formatting and conditional logging but that doesn't work for error_log directive.

Please suggest if there is anyway?